# How can a woman become master of a darkasher in Carnival Row?

Tags: carnival-row

Basically this entire question is a spoiler for *Carnival Row*, so...

> In the Amazon Original series *Carnival Row*, a darkasher is a flesh golem composed of parts taken from multiple deceased animals, which is permanently bound to its master, meaning it acts according to its master's will and cannot die as long as its master lives. What little bits of the creation process of a darkasher we get to see on screen indicate that the master's semen is required--or in the words of the creator "that which would be your part of any creation". However, the primary antagonist turns out to be a woman who is the master of a darkasher. Obviously, women cannot produce semen, so...

...as the title says, how can a woman become the master of a darkasher?

Comment: Menstrual blood can contain an unfertilized egg....

Comment: Maybe she is a transgender woman?

Comment: @Lexible Nope. The character is married to a cishet man and has two biological children, so definitely has working female anatomy.

Comment: @Adamant's sounds like it, then! :)

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley - Well, while it's a fairly good bet that Breakspear is cisgender, the most that we can say is that he is *probably* heterosexual. His romance with Philo's mother does not rule out the possibility of him being bisexual. But in any case, his sexuality, unlike his sex, is not particularly relevant to that matter.

Answer (score 1):

**The seer never actually says that only semen works.** She only says that the creation of a darkasher requires, as stated in the question, "that which would be your part of any creation," which could mean anything from gametes in general, to any part of one's body, to anything that contains one's DNA.

The last two possibilities seem most likely, since in the second season, we see Tourmaline, who has been granted magic similar to that of the seer, create a mental connection with a Sparas using one of its teeth. Admittedly, this is not quite the same as the creation of a darkasher, but the magical principles at play seem similar: the creator of a darkasher creates a mental link with the creature to control it, and can make it move a certain way by pantomiming said movement, which is exactly what we see happen with the character who uses this mental connection to attack the Sparas.

If something with DNA or something from one's body is all that is necessary to make the connection with the darkasher, then anything could have worked. Piety could have used blood or pretty much anything.

One might protest that if this were the case, the seer would have mentioned it more explicitly so that Philo had another option. Well, I don't know if you noticed, but the Haruspex was *super creepy*, as evidenced by the fact that she used magic to rape Philo (instead of *asking* him for his contribution) and transferred parts of her soul, powers, and compulsions to Tourmaline without so much as a how-do-you-do. Her preference for that method probably should not be read as indicating that *only* semen works, just that *she* wanted to do things that way.